# How do you target a window that isn't on screen?

Tags: java

I want to know how to target a window that is offscreen, minimized, etc. In otherwords i want my application to work while the window is minimized doing something. Right now I am trying to use the Robot class to type in another window while it's minimized, but i haven't been able to find out how to do that in java. Is there an external library or method that can let me do this?

Comment: Use a scripting language to do it will be far easier than using Java.

Comment: I suppose you are using awt to do this.Use a thread to do the part when the screen is minimised and it should work

Comment: @Anoopsaju Are you sure Java apps can still listen to key strokes when the window is out of focus?

Comment: Sounds weird to me. Do you expect your application to be still interactive while it is minimized? What's the point on it? Being minimized, a window is not able to get user events.